# select specific field from mongo collection not working

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, python-3.7

I have a collection called `tabelas with data`such as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cdcd4669dc6d6274f2234dc"), 
  "id" :  "recdj5bcTznLBGtbY", 
  "fields" : { "id_tabela" : "tab0005" }, 
  "createdTime" : "2018-08-13T19:15:26.000Z" }
```

I am trying to create an array with just the values given by `"id_tabela"`, in this case, my result would be `["tab0005"]`.

I tried, using pymongo to get first the `"fields"` values and later to get the `id_tabela` values. But I am not even getting the `fields` values.

```
tabelas = db.get_collection("tabelas")
db.drop_collection("tabelas")
result_tabelas = tabelas.insert_many(lista_tabs)

tabelas = db.get_collection("tabelas") 
tab_array = list(tabelas.find())

vec_fields = tab_array['fields']
```

The last line results in an error of the kind:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DWe_9Y2WQR3) as well

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": False,
    "array": {
      "$addToSet": "$fields.id_tabela"
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: brings the error:

         "_id": null,
        NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: In Python `null` is considered as variable. You can use `false` instead.